# How to retrieve data from a database using its ID? Using PDO and psql

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, psql

I have a list of records and when a certain record is clicked on I need it to show the data for that record which is stored in a database.

I want to use the ID of the record so that I can display data from each certain ID, so when a record with ID '1' is clicked on it should display the data from the database with the ID of 1... And so on.

Not sure how else to explain this.

```
<?php
    try {
    $db = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=441255;host=150.237.105.37;user=******;password=*********');
    $id = intval ($_GET['recordid']);
    $SQLquery = "select recordname,recorddetails from record where recordid=$id";

    $results = $db->query($SQLquery);


    print "<table cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"3\"><tr><th>Details</th></tr>\n";

    while ($record =$results->fetch (PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ) {
    print '<h1>' .$record->recordname. '</h1>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' .$record->recordid. '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $record->$id. '</td>';
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }   
    print "</table>\n"; 
}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e;
}
?>
```

This is my PHP code so far, but it is not displaying the data. There are no errors and the URL is changing the ID number for each record, displaying: /IM/record.php?=id1 when the first record is clicked and /IM/record.php?=id2 when the second is clicked.

I'm using PDO and pgsql.

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: The URL should end with `?id=[number]`, not `?=id[number]`

Comment: The URL should be `?recordid=NUMBER`

Comment: like `www.domain.com/page.php?id=1`

Comment: in your case `IM/record.php?id=1`

Comment: **Don’t** use PHP variables directly in your statements. Prepare your statements instead.

Comment: Nevermind, got that section to change now, thanks! But still not getting the data from the database to show.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are totally missing the crucial part of the code.

You say your URL is `/IM/record.php?=id1` when it should be  `/IM/record.php?id=1`, also you are getting the wrong variable via `$_GET`

```
 $id = intval ($_GET['recordid']);
```

should be

```
 $id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

Remeber to check if the $id actually exists as well `isset($id)`

Answer (score 0):

First check if your URLs are correctly created. GET parameters are passed like this: `?[param_name1]=[value1]&[param_name2]=[value2]`... Try to print the received ID to check if you are receiving something at all.

Also in you second cell (td element) you will get an error. `$record->$id` should be just `$id` or `$record->recordid`.

The query itself seems good.